# awk double quote field separator

Tags: python, xml, xslt, awk

I can't seem to figure out my last piece to achieve my desired output.

I have a file with many entries like the following:

```
<Stats>
    <RecNum>45435</RecNum>
    <Date>2016/12/31</Date>
    <DayofWeek>6</DayofWeek>
    <Time>16:35</Time>
    <Dir>Closing</Dir>
    <Class>2</Class>
    <SpeedSpan>1</SpeedSpan>
    <TimeSpan>1</TimeSpan>
    <Bucket Speed="34" Count="1"/>
    <Bucket Speed="35" Count="0"/>
    <Bucket Speed="36" Count="1"/>
</Stats>
```

I want to print the date, time and speed if Count=1 as following:

```
2016/12/31  16:35   34
2016/12/31  16:35   36
```

The closest I have come is the following:

```
$ awk -F'[ <>]' 'BEGIN {d="d";t="t";} /<Date>/ {d=$3;} /<Time>/ {t=$3;} /Count="1"/ {print d "\t" t "\t" $3;}' speed.xml
```

Which gives me:

```
2016/12/31  16:35   Speed="34"
2016/12/31  16:35   Speed="36"
```

I have tried many different iterations, but can't seem to get just the speed number without the wording. I tried to use the " as a field separator, but it never seems to work as expected.

Was hoping to find an awk solution, but if not, I can always use a python program to strip out the unwanted characters.

Comment: checkout: [sub(regexp, replacement)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jose Ricardo Bustos M.'s helpful XSLT-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41917105/45375) and [Stephen Rauch's helpful Python-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916769/45375) are preferable, because they employ proper XML parsing, which is both more flexible and robust.

To fix your `awk` command:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -F'[<>]' '
  /<Date>/ {d=$3}
  /<Time>/ {t=$3} 
  /Count="1"/ {
    split($0, flds, "\"")
    print d, t, flds[2]
  }
' speed.xml
```

`split($2, flds, "\"")` splits the line of interest by `"` and stores the result in custom array `flds`, which allows extracting the `"Speed"` attribute value by index 2.

Also note the use of `-v OFS='\t'` - i.e., setting the output-field separator to a tab - which enables a simpler `print` statement that enumerates (`,`) the output fields, relying on `awk` to implicitly separate them with `OFS`.

---

Afterthought: adding `"` to the set of field-separator characters would have worked too:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -F'["<>]' '
  /<Date>/ {d=$3}
  /<Time>/ {t=$3} 
  /Count="1"/ { print d, t, $3 }
' file
```

Comment: Many thanks. This is exactly what I wanted.
I know I could have done it with Python and probably should learn to use XSLT, but it is for a very specific use case so awk was easy enough to use.

Comment: @brettd0g: Understood, and glad to hear that it helped. Just occurred to me that there's a simpler solution  - see my update (though knowing the `split()` technique is generally handy).

Comment: Your simpler solution also worked for me. 
I tried many times to add the double quote to the field separator but it wouldn't work for me. Yours worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Although I like `awk`, I recommend to use `xslt` to do this (With XSLT you can transform an XML document into any text format). [xslt w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xslt.asp)

> file.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Stats/Bucket[@Count='1']">
            <xsl:value-of select="../Date"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../Time"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Speed" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run it. If you're using some kind of Linux/Unix, use the XSLT-1.0 processor `xsltproc` (There are many more) like this:

```
xsltproc file.xsl file.xml
```

you get,

```
2016/12/31  16:35   34
2016/12/31  16:35   36
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned python:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<X>' + my_xml + '</X>')
collection = DOMTree.documentElement
for record in collection.getElementsByTagName("Stats"):
    date = record.getElementsByTagName('Date')[0].childNodes[0].data
    time = record.getElementsByTagName('Time')[0].childNodes[0].data
    buckets = record.getElementsByTagName('Bucket')
    for bucket in buckets:
        x = bucket.getAttribute('Count')
        if int(bucket.getAttribute('Count')) != 0:
            print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (date, time, bucket.getAttribute('Speed')))
```

Data used:

```
my_xml = """
    <Stats>
        <RecNum>45435</RecNum>
        <Date>2016/12/31</Date>
        <DayofWeek>6</DayofWeek>
        <Time>16:35</Time>
        <Dir>Closing</Dir>
        <Class>2</Class>
        <SpeedSpan>1</SpeedSpan>
        <TimeSpan>1</TimeSpan>
        <Bucket Speed="34" Count="1"/>
        <Bucket Speed="35" Count="0"/>
        <Bucket Speed="36" Count="1"/>
    </Stats>
"""
```

Prints:

```
2016/12/31  16:35   34
2016/12/31  16:35   36
```